# React Native Flatlist: Is it possible to get viewableItems without onViewableItemsChanged?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I have two Flatlists and when Flatlist A scrolls I want Flatlist B to centre on an item based on an attribute of the visible item in A. However because the items of B are not all the same width I can't just calculate where the middle is based on view width and screen width.

The other solution I've thought of is to wait until A starts to move B and then use B's onViewableItemsChanged to access the viewableItems array and then scroll B to the centre. But this would mean 2 scrolls instead of one, which feels clunky.

It seems that all I want is to access viewableItems, but I don't know how without onViewableItemsChanged.